# Better way to get the frontmost window of an Application - Swift

Tags: swift

its not hard to get a specified application by name

```
NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications.filter{$0.localizedName == "Safari"}.first
```

but how to get the first window of this application, and perform miniaturize with this window?

something similar with this

```
let app = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications.filter{$0.localizedName == "Safari"}.first
app.frontmostWindow.miniaturize()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the ScriptingBridge

```swift
import ScriptingBridge

let safari = SBApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Safari")

let windowClass = appleEvent(keyword: "cwin")
let miniaturized = appleEvent(keyword: "pmnd")

let windows = safari?.elementArray(withCode: windowClass)
let frontMostWindow = (windows?.firstObject as? SBObject)?.get() as? SBObject
frontMostWindow?.property(withCode: miniaturized).setTo(true)

func appleEvent(keyword: StaticString) -> AEKeyword {
    keyword
        .utf8Start
        .withMemoryRebound(to: DescType.self, capacity: 1, \.pointee)
        .bigEndian
}
```

To be able to run this code you will need a code signed app with the `com.apple.security.automation.apple-events` entitlement set to true (which allows posting of AppleEvents to other applications)